# Extending an $\omega$-tame complex structure

Tags: symplectic-geometry, almost-complex

The following is an execise from Chris Wendl's book *Holomorphic Curves in Low Dimensions*

> Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $A\subseteq M$ a closed subset. Let $J_A$ be an $\omega$-compatible ($\omega$-tame) almost complex structure defined on a neighbourhood of $A$. Show that $M$ admits an $\omega$-compatible ($\omega$-tame) $J$ which restricts to $J_A$ on a neighbourhood of $A$.

There was a hint: Choose any $\omega$-compatible ($\omega$-tame) almost complex structure $J'$ defined on $M$ and a smooth homotopy between $J'|$ and $J_A$ on some neighbourhood of $A$. Then use a cutoff function.

Can anyone offer some help towards a solution of the exercise?

I'm comfortable with the fact that the spaces of $\omega$-compatible/tame almost complex structures on $(M,\omega)$ are non-empty and contractible, so I see the existence of $J'$ and the homotopy in the hint, but I don't understand how to use a cutoff function.

Comment: What does the "smooth homotopy" here mean?

Comment: @DougLiu i.e. a homotopy through smooth maps. $x\mapsto J_t(x)$ should be a smooth almost complex structure for each $t\in I$.

Comment: If $J_A$ is $\omega-$compatible and defined on an open neighborhood $U$ of $A$ : fix a Riemannian metric $g_0$ on $M$ and let $V=A^c$. $g(u,v)=\omega(u,Jv)$ is a Riemannian metric on $U$. Take a POU $\{\rho,\eta\}$ subordinate to the open cover $U,V$ of $M$. Then $g_1=\rho g+\eta g_0$ is a Riemannian metric on $M$. $A\in\Gamma(M,End(TM))$ such that $w(u,v)=g_1(Au,v)$. $J\in\Gamma(M,End(TM))$ is $J=(AA^*)^{-1/2}A$. Is that OK?

Comment: @DougLiu it seems like its going to work. If you fill in the details and write it up as an answer I would most likely accept.

Comment: How about tamed case?